# в vs2017 в winforms не получается обработать левый,правый и двойные клики мышью, что делать?

Tags: winforms, формы

Итак, суть программы очень проста-на форме для правого/левого и двойного правого/левого кликов по обыкновенной кнопке поменять цвет текста на ней. Трудность возникла конкретно в момент когда написал вот это 
'        private void button1_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)'
и тут понеслось [image]

Код:

```
        using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
                using System.ComponentModel;
         using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace _8_задание
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_MouseClick(object sender,MouseEventArgs e)
        {


        }
    }
}
```

Мой микроскопический опыт подсказывает, что решение простое но информацию как конкретно это сделать найти не смог, поэтому прошу помощи у знатоков, заранее спасибо)) И да как поменять цвет кнопок и тд я знаю, конкретно по описанному вопрос.

Comment: А код где? Предъявите пожалуйста

Comment: @axmed2004, я добавил, взгляните пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Итак, решение оказалось простым, нажать на "перейти к коду" и дальше удалить строчку подчеркнутую красным '      this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);'

Еще полезным для новичков будет знать, что всегда можно перейти в свойства самой формы, нажать события (значок молнии) и кликнуть дважды событию, и в итоге в коде у тебя автоматически напишется соответсвующий обработчик. вот так это выглядит [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот это напишется автоматически

```
   private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```